# Mutual friends- SQL Algorithm

Tags: sql, algorithm, social-networking

I'm trying to fetch mutual friends.

I have a table structured like this:

```
 `friends` (   
    `inviter`  int(11) NOT NULL,   
    `accepter`  int(11) NOT NULL,   
    `time` datetime NOT NULL,)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_turkish_ci;
```

My `load_my_friends(##MY ID##);` query is like this:

```
SELECT  p.id , p.name,p.lastname,p.thumb
FROM  friends AS f
RIGHT JOIN  profiles AS p ON ( f.accepter = p.id OR f.inviter = p.id ) 
WHERE  f.inviter = ##MY ID##
OR  f.accepter = ##MY ID##
LIMIT 0 , 5000
```

Could you tell me how I can fetch the mutual friends data.

Note: I'm not using any social-network script like JCOW,Social Engine etc.

---

*Edit for @2*

In the database I have user1,user2,user3,user4,user5..userX

- user1's friends are: 2,3,6,7,8
- user2's friends are: 1,3,4,5,7,8

I want a query which can fetch these results:

```
     | id  | name |lastname| thumb
    1|  3  |raheel|shan    | /img01.jpg
    2|  7  | arqu |x       | /img02.jpg
    3|  8  |abcdef|hijklmno| /img06.jpg
```

Comment: what is your desired result? please provide some sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A query that's probably easy to understand is the following:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM 
    (
       -- all friends of User A
       SELECT accepter AS friend_id FROM friends WHERE inviter IN (##User_A_ID##)
       UNION
       SELECT inviter AS friend_id FROM friends WHERE accepter IN (##User_A_ID##)
    ) AS t1
    -- intersect with
    JOIN
    (
       -- all friends of User B
       SELECT accepter AS friend_id FROM friends WHERE inviter IN (##User_B_ID##)
       UNION
       SELECT inviter AS friend_id FROM friends WHERE accepter IN (##User_B_ID##)
    ) AS t2
    ON t1.friend_id = t2.friend_id

    JOIN profiles p on p.id=t1.friend_id
```

Comment: Good but what happens if both of them have 5000 friends

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone can come up with a much simpler way to do this, but here's my go at it:

```
SELECT id,name,lastname FROM profiles, 
  (SELECT *
   FROM friends 
   WHERE  
       (inviter = 1 OR accepter = 1) 
       AND (accepter IN ( 
             SELECT inviter 
             FROM   friends 
             WHERE  accepter = 2 AND inviter != 1)
          OR accepter IN ( 
             SELECT accepter 
             FROM   friends 
             WHERE  inviter = 2 AND accepter != 1)
          OR inviter IN ( 
             SELECT inviter 
             FROM   friends 
             WHERE  accepter = 2 AND inviter != 1)
          OR inviter IN (
             SELECT accepter
             FROM   friends 
             WHERE  inviter = 2 AND accepter != 1)))
    f
    WHERE id != 1 AND (inviter = id OR accepter = id);
```

where user1's id = 1, and user2's id = 2

Have a look - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15951/8

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want a list of friends that are shared between two users - User_A and User_B - then this might be sufficient:

```
SELECT accepter 
FROM   friends 
WHERE  inviter = ##User_A_ID## 
       AND accepter IN ( 
          SELECT accepter 
          FROM   friends 
          WHERE  inviter = ##User_B_ID## )
```

Join with your profiles-table to get the other related data.

Comment: This query doesn't treat frendship as a symmetric relationship, so whether or not a mutual friend is discovered by this query depends on who was the inviter and who was the accepter in each case. That is, this query only returns mutual friends that were invited to be friends by A and also by B. If the mutual friend was the one who issued the invitation in either case, that mutual friend won't be returned by this query.

Comment: It's working if u1,u2<-QUERY->u3,u2 but u2,u1<-QUERY->u3,u2 returns NULL. So I must make 2 query and my server will be busy :(

Comment: @Alex: you're absolutely right - I didn't think that through, but will post another (hopefully correct) answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM profiles p
WHERE p.id IN (
    SELECT f_id 
    FROM (
        SELECT accepter as f_id FROM friends where inviter IN (1,2)
        UNION
        SELECT inviter as f_id FROM friends where accepter IN (1,2)
    ) friends 
    GROUP BY f_id
    HAVING count(*) > 1
)
```

assuming that friendships are unique rows....

Comment: Thank you for this simple query. I like it but can't it be without using "UNION" ?